# load an fxml to represent a class instance

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I have asked this before but with no response at all, so let me retry wording it and what I have tried.

When I click a button I want to make a new instance of a class:

```
DataCardController specCapture = new DataCardController("NEW CAPTURE");
```

now in my DataCardController I have a few properties I would like to hook up. Currently I have not passed them for simplification, I have just attached one string in the code above called "NEW CAPTURE". 
 I have an fxml file called dataCard.fxml which is an anchorPane with a couple of labels. One of the labels is supposed to represent this 'new capture' string.

Within the DataCardController class I have:

```
public DataCardController(String spectrumName) throws IOException{
      name = spectrumName;
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("dataCard.fxml"));
      loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("dataCard.fxml"));
      loader.setController(this);
      loader.setRoot(this.data);
      Pane newpane = null;
      try {
         newpane = loader.load();
      } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

What I would like to do is when I save my dataCardController Instance, it runs this code and initialises the fxml file. I then want this to load in my initial view in a Box. So I tried adding the extra line:

```
MainPage.spectrumListVBox.getChildren().add(newpane);
```

However this always throws the error at that last line. It returns a null value error. I cannot see how I can display this. I would like to view several instances of this fxml in one view box, and the idea is when I interact with an individual fxml I can refer to the data it represents elsewhere in my code.

Am I even approaching this the right way? I have managed to view the fxml if I load it directly into a pane in my MainPage Controller:

```
Pane newLoadedPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dataCard.fxml"));
spectrumListVBox.getChildren().add(newLoadedPane);
```

But the issue is I do not have a controller assigned to it if I just load the fxml. If I declare the controller in the fxml file it will load the controller but I have no way I know of to assign different variables to different instances.

Please help!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm

Comment: Where are `MainPage.java`, `DataCardController.java` and `dataCard.fxml` in your project? Are they in the same folder? Is `spectrumListVBox` a static instance? Does your codes which directly loads the FXML resides in the same method as your original method? Anyway, you should debug your application and tell us which object in that chain is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

To properly load a resource, you usually do not need to call `getClassLoader()`. Just simply call `getClass().getResource("/dataCard.fxml");` You may need the `/` in front of the fxml file if it's within the resources folder.

In the end your line of code will look like:

```
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/dataCard.fxml"));
```

Also check to make sure that "dataCard.fxml" is under "/src/main/resources".

Comment: Okay,  I believe the fxml is loading correctly, going through the code again, my issue is actually with the line

    MainPage.spectrumListVBox.getChildren().add(newpane);

That is returning a nullPointer.  If I simply enter the line 
    spectrumListVBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello"));

It returns a nullPointer error.  I am not sure why this is not adding to the VBox.  This VBox is being declared at the beginning of my file  using 

@FXML 
public static VBox spectrumListVBox;  

and is declared in the fxml file.  I have tried adding '=null;' to make sure it is initialised.

Comment: Check that in the fxml file you declared `fx:id=spectrumListVBox` and not `id=spectrumListVBox`. The latter is the  CSS id, not the Java object reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have checked that already.   I use Scene Builder to get things up and running and then edit anything I need to manually now I am learning more about FXML code.  But I can confirm that the fx:id matches the declared name in the controller.  I did copy and paste to confirm no spelling mismatch.Still no luck with this.

Comment: The null pointer exception is happening with your vBox. You should open a new question instead of trying to debug it in comments! Also mark my post as the answer if that's what worked for you! Thanks